# How to convert PNG file to base64 and pass it as a value to a JSON array?

Tags: java, base64, decode, encode

I have a png file which i want to convert to a base64 format like so:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA4QAAAOECAYAAAD5Tv....
```

I then wish to pass this value to a JSON Array like this example:

```
"image": [
      "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA4QAAAOECAYAAAD5Tv",
      "87AAAABmJLR0QA/wD/AP+gvaeTAAAXeklEQVR4nO3ZsWrk1x2GYSnMDVgpjAoHvE",
       ... 
 ]
```

How do i split it up so i can pass it as a JSON array with image as the key?

Comment: Why split it? Normally this would be a single string value.

Comment: @KonradRudolph "constant String too long", anyways i recommend byte[]

Comment: @Joel It wouldn't be a constant. It would be generated at runtime from the image data.

Comment: If the image is so large that you get "constant String too long", it shouldn't be stored in a data URI.